# Implement Java interface from Python using PyJnius

Tags: java, android, python, kivy, pyjnius

Is there a way to implement Java interface from Python, for example this [OnPreparedListener interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html)?

I've tried Pyjinius but not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching some documents, I found that Pyjinius can also implement Java interface.

Refer to this document if you want to do this:
https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/blob/98596b37be14b7e0342342c1eaaae740574ba040/docs/source/api.rst